# General solution of $ty'+2y=4t^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Should we left the general solution of the differential equation $t\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4t^2$ as $t^2y=t^4+c$ instead of $y=t^2+c/(t^2)$ ($c$ is an arbitrary constant)? Does the solution $y=t^2+c/(t^2)$ include the particular solution $y=t^2$? Should we make the assumption $t\neq0$ before we simplified the solution $t^2y=t^4+c$ to $y=t^2+c/(t^2)$?

Comment: $y = t^2$ when $c = 0$